# Fetching and Updating Kafka Topic Configurations through Java API

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I'm writing an application to perform a bunch of operations on a kafka topic through the Java API. I'm able to create topic and add partitions. I need help with fetching topic metadata (such as partitions, brokers) and configurations and updating the configurations.

For reference, I want to update the Topic Level configurations provided here -https://kafka.apache.org/documentation#configuration such as cleanup.policy, compression.type etc

Answer (score 4):

You could use code below to print the topic-level configs. Usage of updating config is similar.

> String[] args = {"--zookeeper", "localhost:2181",
>               "--entity-type", "topics", "--entity-name", "test", "--describe"};
>
> ConfigCommand.main(args);

As for getting metadata, please refer to **Finding the Lead Broker for a Topic and Partition** in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+SimpleConsumer+Example:

**ADDED:** Add config fetch&update example using AdminUtils:

```
ZkUtils zkUtils = ZkUtils.apply("localhost:2181/k1", 6000, 10000, JaasUtils.isZkSecurityEnabled());

    Properties pp = new Properties();
    pp.setProperty("delete.retention.ms", "3000000");
    pp.setProperty("file.delete.delay.ms", "40000");
    AdminUtils.changeTopicConfig(zkUtils, "test", pp);
    Properties p = AdminUtils.fetchEntityConfig(zkUtils, ConfigType.Topic(), "test");
    System.out.println(p);
```

Comment: Im trying to achieve the results through Kafka Admin Utils  API

Answer (score 2):

Linking my answer to a similar question, This is how to fetch the config for a topic in Java.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57272855/apache-kafka-client-java-list-topics-and-check-whether-topic-is-log-compacte/57895165#57895165[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57272855/apache-kafka-client-java-list-topics-and-check-whether-topic-is-log-compacte/57895165#57895165%5B1%5D)

The gist is that you need to create an `AdminClient`, then a collection of `ConfigResource` attributes, call the `describeConfigs` method and parse and loop through the `DescribeConfigsResult` to find the specific config you are looking for.

Here is the code, more explanation is in my answer in the link above.

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.Config;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.ConfigEntry;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.DescribeConfigsResult;
import org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigResource;

admin = AdminClient.create(properties);

Collection<ConfigResource> cr = Collections.singleton(new ConfigResource(ConfigResource.Type.TOPIC,"sepoc.ccc4s-check-request-v1"));
DescribeConfigsResult ConfigsResult = client.describeConfigs(cr);
Config all_configs = (Config) ConfigsResult.all().get().values().toArray()[0];

for (ConfigEntry currentConfig : all_configs.entries()) {
  if (currentConfig.name().equals("compression.type")) {
    log.info("compression.type: {}", currentConfig.value());
  }
}
```