# Apache Kafka Client (Java) : List topics and check whether topic is log compacted

Tags: java, apache-kafka

**Background**

We have Apache Kafka managed by Zookeeper in our company. One of our Spring Boot applications needs to check the list of all topic available and also list which ones have log compaction enabled (cleanup.policy=compact).

**Current Code**

```java
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBrokerList);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaConsumerGroup);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

...
...

    public List<String> getTopics() {
        Map<String, List<PartitionInfo>> topics = consumerFactory().createConsumer().listTopics();
        List<String> topicList = new ArrayList<>();
        topics.keySet().remove(CONSUMER_OFFSETS);
        topicList.addAll(topics.keySet());
        return topicList;
    }
```

**Question**

With the above code the application can get the list of topics. Is there a way to also get to know whether the individual topics are log compacted ? What I am looking for is some "Java" way to get the same response that I get when I run the following Apache Kafka CLI command from terminal.

```sh
kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topic TestTopicCompact
```

An example response of this being

```sh
Topic:TestTopicCompact  PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:cleanup.policy=compact
    Topic: TestTopicCompact Partition: 0    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001  Isr: 1001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [AdminClient API](http://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html) to retrieve that information.

- First use [`listTopics()`](http://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#listTopics--) to retrieve the topic list.
- Then use [`describeConfigs()`](http://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#describeConfigs-java.util.Collection-) to get the configuration for each topic.
- Finally, out of the ConfigEntry objects you'll get, you can then filter the topics that have `compact` as the `cleanup.policy`.

This is basically what the `kafka-topics` tools is doing, so you can have a look at its source [`kafka.admin.TopicCommand`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/TopicCommand.scala). Even though it's Scala, the concepts are similar.

Comment: Hmm. It seems to me (from the CLI command) that the AdminClient needs to hook up with the Zookeeper instances in order to get topic descriptions. (when I tried to do it with the broker list, I get the following execption "org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: The broker does not support DESCRIBE_CONFIGS"). The problem is I could not find a way to specify the zookeeper list while creating the AdminClient, that is there is no config property like zookeeper.servers to mention, like there is for borker list (bootstrap.servers).

Comment: In fact when I do "kafka-broker-api-versions --bootstrap-server <our broker list>" among other things I get the following "DescribeConfigs(32): UNSUPPORTED". By the way, the client verison I am using is kafka-clients:2.0.1 and the Kafka cluster version is 0.10

Comment: DescribeConfigs support was added in 0.11. Pre 0.11, topic configurations are only available in Zookeeper. I really recommend upgrading to a more recent Kafka version, 0.10 was released over 3 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Your first need to create a kafka admin client with a properties file.

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.Config;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.ConfigEntry;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.DescribeConfigsResult;
import org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigResource;

admin = AdminClient.create(properties);
```

You then need to use the admin.describeConfigs method,
this method takes a collection of ConfigResources as a parameter as defined below.

```
Collection<ConfigResource> cr =  Collections.singleton( new ConfigResource(ConfigResource.Type.TOPIC, "<Your Topic Name>") 

DescribeConfigsResult ConfigsResult = admin.describeConfigs(cr));
```

With the ConfigsResult you then need to evaluate and parse this datatype, here I hard cast it into a config datatype.

```
Config all_configs = (Config)ConfigsResult.all().get().values().toArray()[0];
```

You need to then iterate through the all_configs datatype which contains many ConfigResource objects. 
Code below builds an iterator loops through and finds the config value for the config for cleanup policy, you can use the same logic to find the config value for other fields.

```
    Iterator ConfigIterator = all_configs.entries().iterator();

    while (ConfigIterator.hasNext()) 
    {
          ConfigEntry currentConfig = (ConfigEntry) ConfigIterator.next();
          if (currentConfig.name().equals("cleanup.policy")) {
                System.out.println(currentConfig.value());
          }
        }
```